# device shell command - app_process not found, android studio

Tags: java, android, shell, process, command

I have just installed android studio on my computer and when im trying to run the basic program of just a blank activity (API 15) with a text box on my LG g4 phone i get this error on the Run section:

```
Target device: lge-lg_h815-LGH81599f1bbcd
Installing APK: E:\MyAndroid\MyApplication2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-  debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.example.yovel.myapplication
Installing com.example.yovel.myapplication
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r  "/data/local/tmp/com.example.yovel.myapplication"
/system/bin/pm[6]: app_process: not found


Launching application: com.example.yovel.myapplication/com.example.yovel.myapplication.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n "com.example.yovel.myapplication/com.example.yovel.myapplication.MainActivity" -a  android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
/system/bin/am[8]: app_process: not found
```

I have searched all over the internet for a solution but couldn't find anythnig.

Things i have tried :

- Restarting Android studio
- Reinstalling Android studio
- Install everything in the SDK manager

I have also tried to run the project on my brother's phone (LG g3 beat) from the same computer and everything worked out fine..

Help Please :(

Comment: no still have this problem

Comment: I have this problem too, any idea what is causing it yet?

Comment: have you removed the daemonsu from "/system/xbin" folder? because there is a symlink to "app_process" with "/system/xbin/daemonsu"